# Pandas DataFrame subselection

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

The code below shows what I would like to do. Is it possible to do it without the iteritems iteration?

Basically I have a DataFrame `df` with a MultiIndex, and I have a smaller, boolean DataFrame `sdf`, without the MultiIndex. I would to use `sdf` as a preselection/mask to set values in `df`.

```
mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A', 'B'], [1, 2]]) 
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]], columns=mi, index=[0, 1]) 
print(df) 
sdf = pd.DataFrame([[True, False], [False, True]], columns=['A', 'B']) 
print(sdf)
for name, value in sdf.iteritems():
        df.loc[value, name] = 10
print(df)
```

output:

```
   A     B   
   1  2  1  2
0  0  1  2  3
1  1  2  3  4

       A      B
0   True  False
1  False   True

    A       B    
    1   2   1   2
0  10  10   2   3
1   1   2  10  10
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df = df.mask(sdf.reindex(df.columns, axis=1, level=0), 10)
print(df)
    A       B    
    1   2   1   2
0  10  10   2   3
1   1   2  10  10
```

Details:

```
print(sdf.reindex(df.columns, axis=1, level=0))
       A             B       
       1      2      1      2
0   True   True  False  False
1  False  False   True   True
```

Comment: Thanks! Also without mask: df[sdf.reindex(df.columns, axis=1, level=0)] =  10